# Test a method which throws an exception using Junit

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am trying to write a test case for a method which throws an exception based on certain logic. However the test case fails as the expected exception and obtained exceptions are different.

Method to test -

```
public void methodA (//parameters) throws ExceptionA
{
certainlogic=//call some method
if (certainlogic)
throw new ExceptionA(//exception details)
else
//code snippet
}
```

Test method -

```
    @Test (expected=ExceptionA.class)
    public void testMethodA
    {
    try
    {
    when (//mock method).thenReturn(true);
    //call methodA
    }
    catch (ExceptionA e)
    {
    fail(e.printStackTrace(e));
    }
    }
```

I am receiving the below error -

```
Unexpected exception, expected<cExceptionA> but was<java.lang.AssertionError>
```

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: share some more code especially of test class. I think you are checking for assertions in catch or finally block.

Comment: Did you assert anything in your test method?

Comment: show the actual code. you claim an AssertionError happened, but the code you show doesn't have any Asserts in it. So, either the Exception wasn't thrown, or you have a failing assert before calling the method that throws the Exception

Comment: Remove the expected. Now you still should get the AssertionError from some assert. You'll see it in the stack trace, can debug the junit test and so on. In eclipse one needs to click the junit tree view for the failed test.

Comment: As they said, you are not relying on exception parameter in Test annotation, but you have an assertion in your test code, which fails.

Comment: I have added the exception handling snippet. If I remove the expected part, I am receiving ExceptionA as failure. However I need to pass the test case as I need to check if I am receiving the expected exception. The method may throw some other exceptions based on the logic and I need to write test cases for each of the exception.

Comment: @Arnab you catch the exception. you shouldn't. that's your problem

Comment: If I don't catch the exception, it will throw me a compilation error.

Comment: Then add `throws ExceptionA` to method signature. `expected=ExceptionA.class` will take care of "exception handling" for you, it will make an assertion.

Comment: It will not give you compilation error if you declare it as `throws` in your test method. Remove `try-catch` and just declare `throws ExceptionA` in your test method and test it

Comment: @DhawalKapil - Yes this works fine. Thank you.

Comment: Accept @Stefan's answer below. Answer is same as my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remove the `catch` in your test

```
@Test (expected=ExceptionA.class)
public void testMethod()
{
    when (//mock method).thenReturn(true);
    //call methodA
}
```

Otherwise you catch the `ExceptionA` and by calling `fail` you throw an AssertionError. Obviously the `AssertionError` is not an `ExceptionA` and therefore your test fails.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the try-catch block entirely or at least the catch. 
The "expected = ExceptionA.class" tells junit to monitor for thrown exceptions, catch them and compare their class against the given class.
If you catch the thrown exception, the @Test-annotated junit method cannot detect if such an exception is thrown.
By calling fail(...) you implicitly throw an AssertionError which junit detects and thus your test fails because AssertionError.class != ExceptionA.class